# Publish Android library with another module as dependency

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I have project structure with 3 modules: `:library`, `:shared` and `:internal`.
Dependencies between them are following:

`:library` --*depends on*--> `:internal` via **implementation**
`:library` --*depends on*--> `:shared` via **api**
`:internal` --*depends on*--> `:shared` via **implementation**

So, `:library` uses `:internal`, **without** exposing it and `:shared` **exposing** it.
Additionally, `:internal` uses `:shared` as well.

---

**Question:** How do I publish `:library` module, using `maven-publish` Gradle plugin and include other modules sources?

Currently, my publishing looks like this (*build.gradle.kts* of `:library`):

```kt
publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("release") {
            groupId = Project.GROUP_ID
            artifactId = Project.ARTIFACT_ID
            version = Project.VERSION
            from(components["release"])
        }
    }
}
```

But after publishing (I use JitPack) and adding it as dependency in *build.gradle* file of another project, I get following errors, trying to build it:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find [:shared module].
     Required by:
         project :app > [`:library` module]
```

How do I provide my dependency modules to published one?

Comment: Any solution? I'm stuck here too

Comment: @AbdulMateen I've found a [request for this feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62121508), but it is already 5 years old and doesn't seem to be actively worked on

Comment: Yeah I found this too. For me, I had to publish my internal libraries to a remote Maven repo in order for them to work which isn't ideal.